# Add tag for money

Tags: discussion

There should a money tag or if there already are appropriate tags for money related law they should be easier to find. I just asked this question and wanted to tag it money:

[What are the legal implications of "finding" money?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/1636/926)

If that's an appropriate tag, someone please add it.

Comment: Are there special rules around the treatment of money, or is it treated like other property?

Comment: You mean on this SE or as a matter of law? In either case, I have no idea! I just think it would be helpful for organizing questions.

Answer (score 1):

We created [money](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) because there are special laws about "money" that don't apply to less fungible forms of "property."

*However, in the referenced question it's unclear that any such special characteristics are involved*, so it is presently tagged [property](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/property).

As examples:

1. "Money" can concern "negotiable" instruments and "legal tender."  I.e., property and contracts that *must* be accepted for the satisfaction of debts.
2. One can get into legal trouble for attempting to cross a national border with more than $10k in undeclared "money," but not the same value of less fungible "property."

Comment: The [tag:money] tag is probably going to disappear overnight unless it's assigned to a question, though.

Comment: Disappears overnight?  Yet another unfortunate but common characteristic of money ;)

Comment: ... aaand it's gone :/

Comment: Wah!  All my work writing that wiki!  Gone, like teardrops in the rain!